# RViz plugin to visualize camera FOV

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-melodic, camera, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

Is there any RViz plugin which renders the field of view of a camera (like a 2D sector or 3D cone) in RViz?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401652/rviz-plugin-to-visualize-camera-fov/) by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2022-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a package `rviz_visual_tools` which implements a field of view in RViz:

- https://github.com/RoboticsYY/rviz_visual_tools
- https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/1070#issuecomment-514142891
- https://github.com/PickNikRobotics/rviz_visual_tools/pull/117

I hope you can get what you wanted out of it

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) on 2022-05-31**:
Thanks a lot for your answer @ljaniec ! This definitely looks helpful. I also figured out one more way: there is a ROS message of type '[Range](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Range.html)' in the package sensor_msgs. It has quite relevant parameters which can be used (though ti seems to be for ultrasound and infrared sensors). Thanks again!